# Rewrite URLs in Tomcat from dynamic appName to existing context

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting

My Tomcat server is running two different contexts with URLs like this:

**myhost.url/context1/…**

**myhost.url/context2/…**

I want to capture requests to:

**myhost.url/appname/…**

Where appname is dynamic, and redirect those requests to:

**myhost.url/context2/appname/…**

One constraint is to ignore any rewrite in case the request is addressed to **myhost.url/context1/…** or to some static files under the ROOT context.

I want to use Tomcat's RewriteValve to rewrite the URLs hence I added an ROOT context with the following configuration:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>


<Context docBase="ROOT" reloadable="false" crossContext="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve"/>
</Context>
```

And added a rewrite.config file under WEB-INF directory with the following configuration:

```
RewriteCond  %{CONTEXT_PATH} ^(?!/context1/).+$     [OR]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  ^(?!/favicon.ico)          [OR]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  ^(?!/blank.html)           [OR]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  ^(?!/error.html)           [OR]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  ^(?!/index.html)
RewriteRule  ^/(.+)$                /context2/$1    [L]
```

Unfortunately this isn't work, please recommend on a correct rewrite rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to perform the rewriting table in way that satisfies my requirements.

The rewrite will occur only in case the requested context is different from 'context1' or 'context2' and the context is available (successfully deployed).
Or in case the requested url is different from '/', '/favicon.ico', '/blank.html', '/error.html', '/index.html' & '/images'.

```
RewriteCond  %{CONTEXT_PATH} ^/(?!(context1|context2))  [OR]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/(?=.+$)((?!(favicon.ico|blank.html|error.html|index.html|images)).*$)
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$               /context2$1   [L]
```